# Modifying a view runtime?

Tags: views

I wanted to remove click sort from a view and couldn't find anything. So I tried to force:

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_views_pre_view().
 */
function sd8_views_pre_view(ViewExecutable $view, $display_id, array &$args) {
  if ($view->id() === 'content' && str_starts_with($display_id, 'embed') && \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() === 'entity.user.canonical') {
    $display_data = $view->storage->get('display');
    $info = &$display_data['default']['display_options']['style']['options']['info'];
    foreach ($info as &$column) {
      $column['click sortable'] = FALSE;
    }
    $view->storage->set('display', $display_data);
  }
}
?>
```

Even for me, that's some spectacularly ugly code. And it doesn't even work. How could this be done?

Comment: You should be able to control this via views_ui.

Comment: I have indeed built around the problem with the UI but creating a new embed for every use is just not a real solution. This 100% can be done from code it's just so convoluted.

Comment: @̷c̷h̷x̷ An alternative is to disable link via [template file](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/9.5.x/core/modules/views/templates/views-view-table.html.twig#L71)